# Return all hashes based on user id as key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I got an array with hashes. Inside those hashes has a unique user id. I need to return all of that user's likes:

```
p = Post.first
all_likes = p.likes

# This returns: [0][1][2] etc
# inside a hash looks like:
[0] #<Like:0x007f81d3dfb310> {
 id: => 4,
 user_id: => 1,
 like_sent: => 1 # this will always be one
}
```

Let's assume that `all_likes` has many users and I need `user_id: 1`'s total `like_sent`. How to get that?

```
all_likes.find {|f| f["user_id"] = current_user.id } # this returns one hash. I need to return all if more is found.
```

So *if* "Jason" likes a post 10 times, I need to grab his total likes. **How to return all matching hashes**. That's the perfect question.

Comment: Are You tried ```all_likes.where 'user_id = ?', current_user.id```

Comment: At least you are not a General Failure!! That works. Wanna post this as the answer and I'll accept it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
all_likes.where 'user_id = ?', current_user.id
```

And `find` method has some different syntax, something like this:

```
all_likes.find :all, :conditions => ['user_id = ?', current_user.id]
```

Look [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class)

Comment: Please note that hash style of finding is depreciated as of [Rails 4.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) and officially removed as a dependency in [Rails 4.1](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders). So your first answer is the most generically correct although I would suggest updating the syntax to `.where(user_id: current_user.id)`